# using Pos in backend (admin panel)

Tags: php, silverstripe, data-objects

How i can show my pos in summary fields on my data object (gridfield)?

```
private static $summary_fields = array(
        'ID' => 'Whole',
        'Content' => 'Content',
    );
```

the $Pos is only available in SS template and i can't use it in Summary fields

Answer (score 0):

You can define `summaryFields()` as a function.

```
public function summaryFields()
{
  $fields = [];
  foreach (range(1,5) as $num) {
    $fields['Field'.$num] = 'Field ' . $num;
  }

  return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I asked my problem in a bad way, every row of gridfield have Pos variable i want to show my pos in that row or showing the pos as a readonlyfiled near my other fields